# How to add line to a txt file in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I have a **logging** txt file for my bans and kicks to keep track of them in my dc bot.

The log file gets really messy after the first ban because i do not know how to yet the logs to separate lines in the file.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Use the newline control character (`\n`), for example: `var x = "a\nb\nc";` will print `a`, `b` and `c` on newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so as you have not provided any code, I can just guess how you are doing it. Lets say you have a variable `let str = ""` where you add your bans to. In this case you can simply do:

```js
str += `Banned/Kicked ${user.tag}, because ${reason}.\n`;
```

`\n` would add a new line for each new ban/kick. Let's say we have two banned users. The name of the first one is `Example#0001` and the reason was `Test`. The name of the second user is `Example#0002` and the reason was `Test2`. This would be the output:

```
Banned/Kicked Example#0001, because Test.
Banned/Kicked Example#0002, because Test2.
```

Comment: Yeah, i got it now. Thanks!